# How do I get the PostgreSQL PHP extension working on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, postgresql

Will you be so kind to tell me why the sysytem can't load the PostgreSQL extension for PHP?
In php.ini I write:

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

But when I reboot, I get this warning:

> Unable to load dynamic library: C:/PHP/exe\php_pgsql.dll.

There are no problems with other extensions.

Comment: Can you try using only forward backslashes `/` in the path? Did the DLL come with your PHP package, or did you download it later?

Comment: DLL was with PHP package. PHP 5.2.6. OS WINDOWS XP SP2.

Comment: I use forward backlashes, I don't know why the system use another last backlash.
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure php_pgsql.dll actually exists in c:\php\ext.  If so, then you are likely missing libpq.dll, or Windows is unable to locate it at run-time.

libpq.dll should be in c:\php, and c:\php should be part of the PATH system variable.

Using [dependancy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), you can open php_pgsql.dll and see what DLL's it depends on to load and which ones Windows is unable to automatically find.